# Load just ids of relation (pluck)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a simple app, using Laravel 5.5.13.

```
public function index()
{
    return Pet::all();
}
```

This lists all pets. I have many to many relation where many users can own a the same pet (the pet's human family).

I want to load those users.

Doing `return Pet::with('users')->get();` does the trick, however it loads all kind of excessive infromation, like the users api_token etc, I just want to pick some fields, like id and name:

[image]

I was hoping to just get `users: [1, 12]` for the example in the screenshot above.

I tried pluck like this `return Pet::with('users')->get()->pluck('id')` but this gives me only the ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only looking to get user IDs where all the matching users have at least one pet, you can try:

```
// Retrieve all users that have at least one pet
return User::has('pets')->get(['id']);
```

In case I'm misunderstanding you and you still want all of the Pet information, you can use a colon to fetch specific columns in a relation:

```
// Returns all Pets, along with their users' IDs
return Pet::with('users:id')->get();
```

- [Querying Relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations), Querying Relationship Existence
- [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading), Eager Loading Specific Columns

Comment: Thank you sir this is very cool! It is much closer to what I needed but not exactly, may you please adivse: I do need to list all the pets infos, not the users who have at least one pet. With `Pet::with('users:id')->get()` it is now giving me: an array of objects but it includes the pivot - https://screenshots.firefoxusercontent.com/images/e728c34c-6bf3-4b37-b05c-2b9729cecde9.png -

Answer (score 5):

You can select specific fields like this:

```
Pet::with(['users' => function($query) { $query->select('id', 'name'); }])->get()
```

Comment: Thank you this is very cool! However I needed just an array of ids in the users entry. It is giving an array of objects including `pivot` - https://screenshots.firefoxusercontent.com/images/e728c34c-6bf3-4b37-b05c-2b9729cecde9.png

Comment: maybe this works for you

`Pet::with(['users' => function($query) { $query->select('id', 'name')->without('pivot'); }])->get()`

Comment: Thanks @Leonardo but its not removing pivot :(, Its also still an array of objects with `{ id:12 }` rather then array of id integers :(